# Redirect to index location when location did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i would like to redirect to index route when the routes dont match

route.js

```
<Route path={"/"} component={BulletinBoardApp}>
    <IndexRoute component={BulletinBoardAppItems} />
    <Route path={"savedMessages"} component={BulletinBoardAppItems} />
    <Route path={"urgentMessages"} component={BulletinBoardAppItems} />
  </Route>
```

if i do http://localhost:3000/#/savedMessa i get warning

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/savedMessa" did not match any routes
```

I wanted to redirect to http://localhost:3000. Is there a way to do that?

OR

What would be the preferred/right solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Put * in path so that whenever it will not match with any route it will redirect to the default one you will mention.

```
<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
```

Create PageNotFound component.